# Prevent CDK from creating a new OpenSearch domain

Tags: aws-cdk, amazon-opensearch

I modified some parameters of our OpenSearch domain and did a new CDK deploy. Turns out that CDK decided to create a new cluster and redirect both the lambda that performs search and the Fargate task that indexes new documents to this new cluster. So now I have a cluster with 100k documents that is not connected to anything and a search cluster that doesn't have any index or documents.

Creating a snapshot of the old cluster and restoring this to the new cluster solves this, but how do I prevent it?

I made some security policy changes to the cluster so I assume that's the reason CDK created a new cluster, but I was not given any warning that this would happen.

Is there a way to prevent CDK from creating new search domains like this?

Comment: What change did you make? If you look at the docs, some changes require the recreation of a resource. Did you want it to warn you or just stop? The CDK just works off the hard limitations already in place.

Comment: You should use `cdk diff` to see what modify/create/destroy.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I enabled fine_grained_access_control and there is nothing in the CDk docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_opensearchservice/Domain.html)  saying that this requires recreation of the domain. I would expect CDK to stop and ask for confirmation like it does with security changes.

Comment: @vumdao cdk diff shows that this will require replacement. My main issue is that this is such a substantial replacement that there should be safety in place.